What is the name of the book about a boy dressed in layers of clothes who is actually a mouse?
A boy in a classroom wearing layers of clothing is asked to take off his clothing and is revealed not to be a boy but a mouse. I believe it might have been a scholastic book

This could be one of the stories in Sideways Stories from Wayside School.
From the Wikipedia summary,

On a rainy day, a new kid named Sammy comes to Wayside School. However, something about him does not seem right due to his odor and many raincoats. As Mrs. Jewls attempts to remove his raincoats, each one smellier than the previous, Sammy begins to insult her and the other students; she writes his name on the board, checks it, circles it, and (in an unusual extension of the violation system) draws a triangle around the circle. After removing all of Sammy's raincoats, all that remains is a dead rat. Because Mrs. Jewls dislikes dead rats, Sammy is thrown away. It is revealed that dead rats frequently try to sneak into her classroom, this being the third since September.


Oh man... the memories of that series.

Almost definitely this.

Just read this to my kid two nights ago!
